# How to rename misnamed files with their appropriate extensions?

Tags: shell, rename, mime-types, file-types

I have a folder with the bulk of files in it of different types, i.e *.pdf*,*.jpg*,*.png*,*.tiff* etc., but all are named with the extension *.JPG*.  How can I rename all of them with their original extensions? i.e *pdf* to *pdf*, *tiff* to *tiff* and so on.

I can find the file type by:

```
file 99.jpg
99.jpg: PDF document, version 1.3
```

Is there any script or program with which I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Generate the commands *without* running them.

   Use `mimetype` to generate a list of command strings, which is
   thereafter tweaked by *GNU* `sed`'s *substitute* `s` command:

   ```
   cd ~/messed/up/folder/  # go where the files are...
   mimetype -M --output-format 'mv "%f" "%f%m"' *.JPG |
      sed 's#\.[^./"]*/\([^./]*"\)$#\.\1#'
   ```
2. If some of the file extensions look a little too *mime*-ish, (i.e.
   `.jpeg` instead of `.jpg`, etc.), then add as many `s` commands as
   needed between `sed '` and `s`, for example:

   ```
   sed 's/jpeg"$/jpg"/;s#\.[^./"]*/\([^./]*"\)$#\.\1#'
   ```
3. Once the output looks good, run that with the *GNU* `sed`'s
   *evaluate* `e` option.  (Just put an `e` before the final `'`.)  So the whole thing might look like:

   ```
   cd ~/messed/up/folder/  # go where the files are...
   mimetype -M --output-format 'mv "%f" "%f%m"' *.JPG |
       sed 's/jpeg"$/jpg"/;s#\.[^./"]*/\([^./]*"\)$#\.\1#e'
   ls  # show results
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the MIME type found by `file`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash
for f in ./*.JPG; do
    type=$(file -bi "$f")
    type=${type%%;*}
    base=${f%.*}
    final=
    case "$type" in
        application/pdf) final="$base".pdf ;;
        image/png)       final="$base".png ;;
        image/tiff)      final="$base".tiff ;;
    esac
    if [ "$final" ]; then
        printf '%s --> %s\n' "$f" "$final"
        # mv -f "$f" "$final"
    fi
done
```

Add more types to the `case` if you need to (but leave out `image/jpeg`, since JPEG files already have the right extension).  Review the changes, then uncomment the `mv` line when you're happy with the results.

Comment: You reverted my changes but your script will fail when files are named  like `-filename`. The `--` will take care of that.

Comment: @val0x00ff Nope, I reverted that part of your script because it isn't needed.  Because of `./*.JPG`, `file` and `mv` will see `./-filename`, not `-filename`.  Please pay attention before "fixing" other people's posts.

Comment: You know it's worthless to discuss this since my comment probably didn't arrive on time. Your original post didn't include the `./` and that's why I suggested the `-- (End of options)` syntax.

Comment: @val0x00ff My [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/368504/revisions#rev-arrow-b83cb4c8-47a6-4157-b11f-0c4a7af8e1ae) was posted 6 minutes after the initial revision (what can I say, I'm an old fart). Your comment was posted almost 8 hours later, and it was about me reverting your changes, not about my initial revision.  The reverted version was (and still is) 100% correct.